# Is there a pure NumPy way to create an array of ND indicies and values?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, numpy-ndarray

This script creates an array `b` of indices and values of given array `a`, which is useful for example in conversion of 2.5D height map to a point cloud:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.arange(12).reshape(3, 4)
b = np.array([[*i, val] for i, val in np.ndenumerate(a)])
print(b)
```

```
[[ 0  0  0]
 [ 0  1  1]
 [ 0  2  2]
 [ 0  3  3]
 [ 1  0  4]
 [ 1  1  5]
 [ 1  2  6]
 [ 1  3  7]
 [ 2  0  8]
 [ 2  1  9]
 [ 2  2 10]
 [ 2  3 11]]
```

Is there a pure NumPy way, i.e. no loop, to do the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of many possible ways:

```
In [129]: np.hstack((np.argwhere(np.ones((3,4))),np.arange(12)[:,None]))
Out[129]: 
array([[ 0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  1,  1],
       [ 0,  2,  2],
       [ 0,  3,  3],
       [ 1,  0,  4],
       [ 1,  1,  5],
       [ 1,  2,  6],
       [ 1,  3,  7],
       [ 2,  0,  8],
       [ 2,  1,  9],
       [ 2,  2, 10],
       [ 2,  3, 11]], dtype=int64)
```

Another:

```
In [144]: arr = np.concatenate((np.mgrid[:3,:4],np.arange(12).reshape(1,3,4)))

In [145]: arr
Out[145]: 
array([[[ 0,  0,  0,  0],
        [ 1,  1,  1,  1],
        [ 2,  2,  2,  2]],

       [[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
        [ 0,  1,  2,  3],
        [ 0,  1,  2,  3]],

       [[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
        [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
        [ 8,  9, 10, 11]]])

In [146]: arr.reshape(3,-1).T
Out[146]: 
array([[ 0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  1,  1],
       [ 0,  2,  2],
       [ 0,  3,  3],
       [ 1,  0,  4],
       [ 1,  1,  5],
       [ 1,  2,  6],
       [ 1,  3,  7],
       [ 2,  0,  8],
       [ 2,  1,  9],
       [ 2,  2, 10],
       [ 2,  3, 11]])
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with:

```
b = np.column_stack((
    np.indices(a.shape).reshape(a.ndim, -1).T,
    a.ravel()
))
```

`np.indices` is typically used to generate an array of all possible indices. Here it is just transposed and reshaped to form all but the last column in `b`.

`np.column_stack` seems the most natural to finally concatenate the indices to the raveled `a`.

The above should work for any dimensional `a`.